# How could i change a checked checkbox value from "true" and "false" to another word?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Andoid Studio to develop my App. In My App i want to get the name of a selected Checkbox to an Email Intent. It Works, but when checkbox is selected the emailtext shows : checkboxname:true and when its not selected the emailtext  shows : checkboxname:false. How could i change the words "True" and "False" into other words like "Ja" or "Nein" ? Is this possible ?

```
emailIntent = emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"checkBox1.isChecked"());
```

Here is the Whole Intent:

```
 emailIntent = emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Reparaturmeldung/Techniker Anforderung :"
                                            + "\n\nFirma: " + Firma.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n Ihr Name: " + IhrName.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n Strasse Hausnummer: " + StrasseHausnummer.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n PLZ/Ort: " + PLZOrt.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n Telefonnummer: " + Telefonnummer.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n Email Adresse: " + EmailAdresse.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n Hersteller: " + Hersteller.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n Modell: " + Modell.getText().toString()
                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox1.getText().toString()+ checkBox1.isChecked()
                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox2.getText().toString()+ checkBox1.isChecked()
                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox3.getText().toString()+ checkBox1.isChecked()
                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox4.getText().toString()+ checkBox4.isChecked()
                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox5.getText().toString()+ checkBox5.isChecked()
                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox6.getText().toString()+ checkBox6.isChecked() 
                                            + "\n Sonstige Fehlerbeschreibung: " + SonstigeFehlerbeschreibung.getText().toString());
```

Somwhow it did not work like I want it. I have another Question with this checkbox intent. Is it possible to get only the selected checkbox value (text) to my email intent and the not selected checkboxes would not shown ?!

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the checkbox is selected prior.

```
String toPass = "Nein";
if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
    toPass = "Ja";
}

emailIntent = emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,toPass);
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line , you can use -

```
emailIntent = emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,checkBox1.isChecked() == true ? "YES" : "NO");
```

For multi line text, 
you can declare a new string -

```
String trueText = "Fehler: " + checkBox1.isChecked()
                                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox2.getText().toString()
                                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox3.getText().toString()
                                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox4.getText().toString()
                                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox5.getText().toString()
                                                            + "\n Fehler: " + checkBox6.getText().toString();


String falseText = "line 1 \n line 2 ";
```

And then

```
 emailIntent = emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,checkBox1.isChecked() == true ? trueText : falseText);
```

Comment: Ok. For one Line it works. but i Have more than 1 line:#

Comment: For multiline you can add '\n' in between your string. This will add a new line  .

Answer (score 0):

ok it works :) Thanks a lot here is my code:

```
private String toPass1() {
        String toPass1 = "Nein";
        if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
            toPass1 = "Ja";
        }return toPass1;
    }
    private String toPass2() {
        String toPass2 = "Nein";
        if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
            toPass2 = "Ja";
        }return toPass2;
    }
    private String toPass3() {
        String toPass3 = "Nein";
        if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
            toPass3 = "Ja";
        }return toPass3;
```

......................same for checkbox 4 -6

and in the Intent:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,

 + "\n" + checkBox1.getText().toString() + ": " + toPass1()
                                        + "\n" + checkBox2.getText().toString() + ": " + toPass2()
                                        + "\n" + checkBox3.getText().toString() + ": " + toPass3());
```

......................same for checkbox 4 -6

Nice !!!